# Issues with matplotlib attribute errors

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributes

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Iris.csv')

plot = plt.scatter(df['SepalLengthCm'], df['PetalLengthCm'])
plot.savefig('ScatterIris.png')
```

I'm trying to do some really basic matplotlib stuff and it keeps raising errors.

```
C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\python.exe 
C:/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/linear_regression/ML.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/linear_regression/ML.py", line 9, in <module>
plot.savefig('ScatterIris.png')
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

First I couldn't use the .show() attribute and then I couldn't use the .savefig() attribute. Is there something wrong with my matplotlib installation?

For reference I tried changing the backend of my matplotib in matplotlibrc to a couple different ones and the same error everytime.

Edit @ nbryans

```
plt.scatter(df['SepalLengthCm'], df['PetalLengthCm']).savefig('ScatterIris.png')
```

Same error comes up

Edit 2:

Yeah you guys were right I can save figures and use the show() attribute/method.
Thanks!

Comment: Should be `plt.savefig()`

Comment: Your edit doesn't matter... You're still trying to call a method (`savefig`) that doesn't exist for `PathCollection` objects.

Comment: So you may choose any of the answers to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (doesn't matter which one, they are all roughly the same), such that this question will not stay unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call pyplot's `savefig` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Iris.csv')

plt.scatter(df['SepalLengthCm'], df['PetalLengthCm'])
plt.savefig('ScatterIris.png')
```

The same is true if you were using the pandas plotting function,

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Iris.csv')
df.plot(kind="scatter", x='SepalLengthCm', y= 'PetalLengthCm')

plt.savefig('ScatterIris.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign a `plot` variable and you should just do `plt.show()`. Try:

```
plt.scatter(df['SepalLengthCm'], df['PetalLengthCm'])

plt.savefig('ScatterIris.png') # or plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `savefig() is a function of pyplot (i.e.`plt`) and not of the recently created`plot`. It saves whatever the current plot you created is. Thus, it should be:

```
plt.savefig()
```

Similarly, just to see your plot, it would be

```
plt.show()
```